# Rails: Messages_Users join model not functioning properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a messaging system (sent messages, received messages, senders, receivers) with `Message` and `User`. Since it's a many to many relationship, I have a join model called `messages_users`

schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121204230411) do

  create_table "messageattachments", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "picture"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "messages", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "messages_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          :null => false
    t.integer  "sent_message_id"
    t.integer  "received_message_id"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

end
```

models:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content

  has_many :messages_users
  has_many :receivers, :through => :messages_users
  has_many :senders, :through => :messages_users

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name

  has_many :messages_users
  has_many :sent_messages, :through => :messages_users
  has_many :received_messages, :through => :messages_users
end


class MessagesUsers < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sent_messages_id, :received_messages_id, :receiver_id, :sender_id

  belongs_to :sent_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "sent_message_id"
  belongs_to :received_messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "received_message_id"
  belongs_to :receivers, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
  belongs_to :senders, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"
end
```

I'm trying to run a simple test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MessageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "has senders" do
    message = Message.create(:content => "hi")
    message.sender = User.first #Am I allowed to an instance of another Model in unit tests?
    assert message.sender.valid?
  end
```

regardless of what I test I always get this errror:

```
# Running tests:

E

Finished tests in 0.083961s, 11.9103 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_has_senders(MessageTest):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "receiver_id" of relation "messages" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "receiver_id", "sender_id...
end
```

Can someone help me out? I don't see any issues with my models..

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.8)
1.9.3-p194 :001 > message = Message.create(:content => "hi")
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (22.6ms)  INSERT INTO "messages" ("content", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "hi"], ["created_at", Tue, 04 Dec 2012 23:58:19 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Tue, 04 Dec 2012 23:58:19 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.8ms)  COMMIT
 => #<Message id: 1, content: "hi", created_at: "2012-12-04 23:58:19", updated_at: "2012-12-04 23:58:19"> 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > message.sender = User.first
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `sender=' for #<Message:0x007f92441ac538>
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/edmundmai/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p194 :003 >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up singular and plural forms. You have `belongs_to :receivers` (plural) but you name the foreign key `receiver_id`:

```
belongs_to :receivers, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"
```

You can of course name these things whatever you want, but the default (and more sensible, IMHO) wording would be to name the association `receiver`.

From the docs on [the `foreign_key` option of `belongs_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to):

> Specify the foreign key used for the association. By default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly, belongs_to :favorite_person, :class_name => "Person" will use a foreign key of “favorite_person_id”.

Likewise, in you assign `message.sender = User.first`, but your `Message` model has no `sender`, it has `senders` (plural). This is why you get the error in the console `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sender=' for #<Message:0x007f92441ac538>`.

If what you want to do is add a sender to a message and check that the message has senders, then I think this would work:

```
test "has senders" do
  message = Message.create(:content => "hi")
  user = User.create(...)
  message.senders << user
  assert message.senders.first.valid?
end
```

Although, to be honest, I don't really see the point of this test. I also don't quite understand why a message has multiple senders. Shouldn't this just be a simple one-to-many relationship? i.e. a message `has_one :sender`. That would make sense to me. In fact, the whole model setup here is a bit confusing, it would help if you could clarify why you've set it up this way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your test database has not been properly created or migrated.

Try running `rake db:create` and `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`

Comment: didn't work... I even dropped the database and recreated and remigrated it and the error still shows up

Comment: i did change the db from sqlite3 to pg midway through though... maybe i didn't do it properly? is there a way to check

Comment: Do you get the same error when you try to do that in the rails console?

Comment: Also, I think on your `belongs_to :receivers, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "receiver_id"`
  `belongs_to :senders, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "sender_id"` I think you meant :sender instead of :senders no?

Comment: do what in the rails console? i checked and my db is postgres

Comment: If you run this in the rails console `message = Message.create(:content => "hi")`
    `message.sender = User.first` does it execute fine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20592/discussion-between-leo-correa-and-edmund)